# Is truth serum used in any psychiatric or psychoanalytic practices?

Tags: methodology, clinical-psychology, psychoanalysis

Is sodium thiopental (truth serum) used in any psychiatric or psychoanalytic therapies?

I presume it is legal for use, since it is [Schedule III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Substances_Act#Schedule_III_drugs), and [it is administered in surgeries](http://www.drugs.com/pro/pentothal.html).  It clearly has use [in criminal interrogation](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/kent-csi/vol5no2/html/v05i2a09p_0001.htm#13-gottschalk-l-a).

I would also take answers that regard the history of its use in psychotherapy.

Comment: Note, that the document of the CIA website is a historical document which is also indicated by the fact that the most recent cited reference is from 1960. Also, I think the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_thiopental) gives already many information and reading the resources might already enough to answer your question.